# Initializing a 2D array with random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, random, 2d

I am trying to initialize my array in a function with random values, so I can (later) sort it.

```
static int a[10][100000]; //declared in int main()

void init(int [10][100000]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        a[i] = rand();
        for(int k = 0; k < 100000; k++){
            a[k] = rand();
        }     
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is your question? Why does the unused argument `arr` exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you got the variable wrong. The argument is `arr`, not `a`.

`a[i] = rand()` makes no sense. `a[i]` is a whole row, you can't assign a number to it. To access an element of a 2-d array, use two subscripts.

```
void init(int arr[10][100000]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 100000; k++){
            arr[i][k] = rand();
        }     
    }
}
```